# Nested $.getJSON() statements?

Tags: javascript, json, api, nested, reddit

I'm working on an extension that searches reddit and returns the title and the post, but I'm trying to get it to display the top 5 comments as well. I have my $.getJSON statement that pulls the comments nested inside the $.getJSON statement that pulls the title/post. For some reason, it posts all the comments under the entire page of posts instead of with their respective post. Is it possible to nest these statements? It may just be a simple formatting issue.
Fiddle in the comments:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/elliotmersch/5tDu5/